# How to conditionally build target and all its dependencies based on values passed to variables in the command line?

Tags: gnu-make

I have looked at documentation of GNU Makefile Conditional Statements, but I couldn't find any information on how to build both the target and its dependencies conditionally.

EDIT: When I say conditionally, I mean dependent on values of variable set in command line while calling make. I apologize for not making it clear earlier.

To add to the above edit. If some variables set in the commandline take a particular value, even if the targets and their dependencies need to be updated, I want to refrain from doing this.

[GNU Makefile Conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html#Conditionals)

Thanks!

Comment: As it stands, your question is much, much too broad. *Every* compilation is conditional on the relative age of the source and object files; this is the purpose of Make. If you need help with the documentation you link to, perhaps [edit] your question to show an example which doesn't behave like you expect. See also the Stack Overflow [help] in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about something like:

```
ALL_TARGETS = foo bar

ifndef SOME_VARIABLE
    ALL_TARGETS += biz baz
endif

all: $(ALL_TARGETS)
```

Now if you run `make` it will build `foo`, `bar`, `biz`, and `baz`, but if you run `make SOME_VARIABLE=true` it will only build `foo` and `bar`.

With the very generic, specifics-free question that's about all we can suggest.

Comment: I'll try this in sometime and confirm. Thanks!

Comment: Also `make ALL_TARGETS="bo beep"` will build `bo` and `beep` instead of (as it were) the default default target... Though `make bo beep` does that much more succinctly.